# Expandable Tableview with last row of every section has Add Button - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, expandable-table

I struck in tableview. I need tableview of collapse and Expand looks like Below,

[image: Table Section Collapse[![Table Section Expand]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyRPb.png)

I need to add 2 buttons for last row of every section.
Could you guide me how to design the below design in ios swift?

Comment: check this code https://github.com/vishalkalola1/SideMenuAndExpandCollapseTableCell

Answer (score 1):

Add your buttons in custom view and feed it in UITableViewDataSource method below:

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView?`

Answer (score 0):

Best way is take Two Button in one cell, and return that cell when **`indexPath.row = lastRow`**
And add tap gesture on header view for collapse view

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cell with two buttons. Next you should add it to your data source and configure it properly. Then add a delegate to your custom `UITableViewCell` and handle taps.